# Implementing IValueConverter interface in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ivalueconverter

i have the following IValueConverter implementation

```
public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri((string)(value), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            var img = new BitmapImage(uri);
            return img;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var img = value as BitmapImage;
        return img.UriSource.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have the following

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var products = new List<Product>()
                     {
                         new Product()
                             {
                                 Name = "Apple",
                                 ImageUrl = @"c:\users\ashutosh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ValueConverter\ValueConverter\Images\Apple.jpg"
                             },
                         new Product()
                             {
                                 Name = "Mango",
                                 ImageUrl = @"c:\users\ashutosh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ValueConverter\ValueConverter\Images\Mango.jpg"
                             }
                     };

        myComboBox.Items.Clear();   
        myComboBox.ItemsSource = products;
    }
}
```

The XAML is as follows

```
<UserControl x:Class="ValueConverter.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:this="clr-namespace:ValueConverter"
    d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="200">
<UserControl.Resources>
        <this:MyValueConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/> 
</UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ComboBox Name="myComboBox"  Height="143" Width="193">
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter},Mode=TwoWay}"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I just see the valueconverter.Product as the items in my combobox.
[image: ComboBox]

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that the `DataTemplate` is the `ItemTemplate` for the ComboBox:

```
  <ComboBox Name="myComboBox"  Height="143" Width="193">
     <!-- Add this! -->
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter},Mode=TwoWay}"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

Comment: this displayed the names of the product , the images are still not getting displayed ...

Answer (score 0):

i made the return like this

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/" + (string)(value), UriKind.Relative));
```

and changed the following

```
ImageUrl = @"Apple.jpg"
```

Initially the BitMapImage was not getting populated with the image , it was showing null . My guess is this had something to do with me supplying bad URI ...So i got it to work !!

Comment: yes you were tring to fetch images from the local file system.  Silverlight won't let you do that.